# Cocos2d-js: some demos don't run on Genymotion

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

I compiled the Cocos2d-js 'Hello World'-project for Android and try to run it on Genymotion (Android emulator on x86).

I already tried adding :

```
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a x86
```

to `Application.mk` , which makes the apk 3 times bigger, but when I run the app in Genymotion it immediately says "HelloWorld has stopped".

The same apk runs fine on a real Android device.

Any ideas ?

***UPDATE:***
The sample JS-MoonWarriors runs fine on Genymotion (with ARM-translation installed), so I guess it has nothing to do with x86. The sample JS-Tests however does *not* work (same error '... has stopped').

Comment: I had a similar problem when running in BlueStacks emulator, but it ended up being a problem with the emulator -a clean reinstall fixed it-. I have no Genymotion expertise, sorry. Have you tried using the regular android emulator that comes with adt-bundle?

Answer (score 2):

Solved it with the help from the following link :
http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-with-genymotion/9476/2

In the file `Cocos2dxActivity.java` is a function that checks if it runs on the default Android emulator.
Change this function to also include Genymotion (and Adobe VirtualBox) :

```
isEmulator = product.equals("sdk") ||
             product.contains("_sdk") || 
             product.contains("sdk_") || 
             product.contains("vbox");
```

Also, you'll have to make sure that the ARM-translation package is installed in Genymotion, or use the APP_ABI trick in the question.

Answer (score 1):

i Solved it too ... and there's two things you should do to make it work:

First search your cocos game project on a file named Cocos2dxActivity.java then open it with notepad and scroll down to the bottom of the file then you should find a static function with a line like this:

```
 isEmulator = product.equals("sdk") || product.contains("_sdk") || product.contains("sdk_");
```

which needs to be changed to this:

```
 isEmulator = product.equals("sdk") || product.contains("_sdk") || product.contains("sdk_") || product.contains("vbox");
```

Second search your cocos game project again for another file called Application.mk and like the usual open it with notepad and under these tow lines:

```
# Uncomment this line to compile to armeabi-v7a, your application will run faster but support less devices
#APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
```

add another line just beneath them :

```
APP_ABI := armeabi x86
```

another thing you should consider is the line you just add should be exactly as i wrote it and if you just try this :

```
APP_ABI := Armeabi x86 (Wrong ... it wont work just because of the capital A)
```

and by the way i am using Cocos code IDE 1.2 to package my apk files with framework v3.7 and android-ndk-r10c And the SDK as the adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702

and one more thing ... you have to install Genymotion-ARM-Translation in your emulator with Gapps in order for this to work.

PS: if you don't find any of the files then you need to recreate your project and with add native code to the project checked in.